# Find all leafes of a binary searchtree by folding

Tags: haskell, binary-tree, fold

I got the task of getting all leafs from a binary tree of this datatype:

```
data Bintree el = Empty |
                  Tree {left :: Bintree el, node :: el, right :: Bintree el} deriving Show
```

Now I have this Treefold function which works perfectly in tests:

```
binTreeFold :: (a -> b -> a -> a) -> a -> Bintree b -> a
binTreeFold f el Empty = el 
binTreeFold f el tree@(Tree leftTree node rightTree) = f (binTreeFold f el leftTree) node (binTreeFold f el rightTree)
```

And I try to get all leafs but somehow it simply doesnt work (Compile issues mentioned below):

```
leavesWithFold :: Bintree a -> [a]
leavesWithFold Empty = []
leavesWithFold tree =  binTreeFold (\left -> \node -> \right -> if (checkIfTreeIsLeaf node) then left ++ [node] ++ right else left ++ [] ++ right) [] tree
```

using the following function:

```
checkIfTreeIsLeaf :: Bintree a -> Bool
checkIfTreeIsLeaf Empty = False
checkIfTreeIsLeaf (Tree Empty node Empty) = True
checkIfTreeIsLeaf _ = False
```

The compiler tells me

```
Couldn't match type `a' with `Bintree a0'
```

But in former functions the use of

```
left ++ [node] ++ right
```

Was working perfectly fine. Have you any idea what I did wrong and probably what I could change?

Best Whishes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well typically the idea of a using a `fold` function is that it does *all* the work for you. So by writing a function that branches into an `Empty` case and a `tree` case, this is already a bit strange.

## A *recursive* approach

But let us simply start with a recursive approach. Forget about folding, etc. for now. How would we generate a list of leaves in general?

Well there are basically three cases here:

1. in case we encounter an `Empty`, then we return the empty list, since `Empty` is *not* a leaf, and we are supposed to return all leaves, so:

   ```
   leaves Empty = []
   ```
2. in case we encounter a `Tree` with `Empty` both as left and right subtree, we know that that `Tree` is a leaf, so we return the element it carries, as a list:

   ```
   leaves (Tree Empty x Empty) = [x]
   ```
3. in case one of the two subtrees (or both) are not `Empty`, we recursively would call the `leaves` function, and concatenate the two together:

   ```
   leaves (Tree l _ r) = leaves l ++ leaves r
   ```

So now in full we got:

```
leaves :: Bintree a -> [a]
leaves Empty = []
leaves (Tree Empty x Empty) = [x]
leaves (Tree l x r) = leaves l ++ leaves r
```

## How to detect through recursion that this *is* a leaf

We of course can not do that with the `binTreeFold` approach. But can't we detect whether a tree is in fact a leaf? In case the two recursive calls *both* result in an empty list, we know that the current `Bintree` is in fact a leaf. Indeed: if the left (and right) subtree are `Empty`, they result in empty lists. And in case these are not empty, then these either are leaves, that will recursively produce a singleton list, or those are not `Tree`s with descendants, that will eventually lead to leaves, and therefore to non-empty lists.

## Encoding this in the *fold* function

So we an first take a look at the recursive calls, and then based on the fact whether these are *both* empty lists, either return a singleton list with the leaf element, or concatenate the two lists together, like:

```
f [] x [] = [x]
f l _ r = l ++ r
```

Or using this in the `binTreeFold` function:

```
leavesWithFold :: Bintree a -> [a]
leavesWithFold = binTreeFold f []
    where f [] x [] = [x]
          f l _ r = l ++ r
```

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly + I understand how it works! :) Thank you